# How to update a TextView with GPS coordinates

Tags: android, gps, textview, coordinates

I am NEW to Android and Java development so please be patient with me :) I am trying to get my phone's GPS coordinates and then updating a TextView with the latitude (I just need the latitude for now). Here's what I have so far:

```
main.xml:

[...]
    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Get my location"
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:onClick="returnMyCoordinates" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:text="This is where the lat value will show up"
    android:id="@+id/latitudeResult" />

MapsActivity.java:

        public void returnMyCoordinates(View v, Location location){
        double latiTude;
        latiTude = location.getLatitude();
        String lat_value;
        lat_value = Double.toString(latiTude);
        TextView latView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.latitudeResult);
        latView.setText(lat_value);
    }
```

It is my understanding that I cannot combine "View v" with other parameters in a Method declaration. If that is true, why is that? And how else could I accomplish this?

Here is the entire file for context:

```
package com.example.googlemapsandroidapi;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.BitmapDescriptorFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback,LocationListener{

    private GoogleMap mMap = null;
    protected LocationManager locationManager;
    Double lat;
    Double long1;
    TextView txtLat;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

    }

        public void returnMyCoordinates(View v, Location location){
        double latiTude;
        latiTude = location.getLatitude();
        String lat_value;
        lat_value = Double.toString(latiTude);
        TextView latView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.latitudeResult);
        latView.setText(lat_value);
    }


     public void showLocation(View v) {
     setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
     SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
     .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
     mapFragment.getMapAsync(MapsActivity.this);

     ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MapsActivity.this,
     new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
     1);

     locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
     try {
     locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 250000, 0, this);
     locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 250000, 0, this);
     if(mMap!=null){
     mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
     }
     Log.e("TAG","Location Manager Called Successfully.");
     }catch (SecurityException e){
     e.printStackTrace();
     Log.e("TAG","SecurityException:"+e.getMessage());
     }
     }


    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case 1:
                if (grantResults.length > 0
                        && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    try {
                        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 250000, 0, MapsActivity.this);
                        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 250000, 0, MapsActivity.this);
                        if(mMap!=null){
                            mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
                        }
                        Log.e("TAG","Location Manager Called Successfully.");
                    }catch (SecurityException e){
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        Log.e("TAG","SecurityException:"+e.getMessage());
                    }
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(MapsActivity.this,"Sorry We Need All Permissions Open App Again and Allow All.",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    MapsActivity.this.finish();
                }
                return;
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;

        // Add a marker in Sydney and move the camera
        /*LatLng sydney = new LatLng(-34, 151);
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title("Marker in Sydney"));
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney));*/
    }


    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String s, int i, Bundle bundle) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String s) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String s) {

    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think you need to add `setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);`

Answer (score 1):

Try initializing the `TextView latView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.latitudeResult);` in the `onCreate` method since i think that your `MapsActivity.java` is an Activity? can you post the whole `MapActivity.java` either way.

Comment: Yes, it is a good practice to instantiate a variable inside a local method if it is only used once but for reusability of that variable you need to declare it in `onCreate`. Since your `returnMyCoordinates` is asking for another parameter you can declare the textView in `onCreate` and then call the setText in `returnMyCoordinates`

Comment: I tried that and I'm getting: "FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  Process: com.example.googlemapsandroidapi, PID: 9582
                  java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find a method returnMyCoordinates(View) in the activity class com.example.googlemapsandroidapi.MapsActivity for onClick handler on view class android.widget.Button with id 'button2'"

Comment: Can I declare multiple parameters if one of them is "View v"?                                           public void returnMyCoordinates(View v, Location location, TextView latView){
        double latiTude;
        latiTude = location.getLatitude();
        String lat_value;
        lat_value = Double.toString(latiTude);
        //TextView latView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.latitudeResult);
        latView.setText(lat_value);
    }

Answer (score 0):

Please try this using all class.
MainActivity.class:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements
    ConnectionCallbacks, OnConnectionFailedListener, View.OnClickListener {


protected GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
protected Location location;
protected boolean mAddressRequested;
protected String mAddressOutput;
private AddressResultReceiver mResultReceiver;
ProgressBar mProgressBar;
private Button btnCurrentLocation, btnShowAddress;
private TextView tvSetLat, tvSetLang, tvAddress;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    setId();
    setListener();

    mProgressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progress_bar);


    updateValuesFromBundle(savedInstanceState);
    buildGoogleApiClient();
}


private void setId() {
    tvSetLat = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvSetLat);
    tvSetLang = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvSetLang);
    btnCurrentLocation = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnCurrentLocation);


}


private void setListener() {
    btnCurrentLocation.setOnClickListener(this);


}

private void updateValuesFromBundle(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

}

protected synchronized void buildGoogleApiClient() {
    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .addApi(LocationServices.API)
            .build();
}


@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
        mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
    }
}

@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle connectionHint) {
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        return;
    }
    location = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);
    if (location != null) {
        if (!Geocoder.isPresent()) {
            Toast.makeText(this, R.string.no_geocoder_available, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return;
        }
        if (mAddressRequested) {
            startIntentService();
        }
    }
}


@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult result) {
    Log.i(TAG, "Connection failed: ConnectionResult.getErrorCode() = " + result.getErrorCode());
}


@Override
public void onConnectionSuspended(int cause) {
    Log.i(TAG, "Connection suspended");
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
}


protected void showToast(String text) {
    Toast.makeText(this, text, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    savedInstanceState.putBoolean(ADDRESS_REQUESTED_KEY, mAddressRequested);
    savedInstanceState.putString(LOCATION_ADDRESS_KEY, mAddressOutput);
    super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
}


@Override
public void onClick(View view) {

    switch (view.getId()) {
        case R.id.btnCurrentLocation:
            if (location != null) {
                tvSetLat.setText(String.valueOf(location.getLatitude()));
                tvSetLang.setText(String.valueOf(location.getLongitude()));
            }
            break;


        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

}

your xml is activity_main

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context="com.example.android.geocoderdemo.MainActivity">

<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/progress_bar"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:weightSum="1">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvSetLat"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight=".50"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:text="set lat" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvSetLang"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight=".50"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:text="set long" />

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:weightSum="1">


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnCurrentLocation"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight=".50"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Get Current Location" />

</LinearLayout>
```

and add permission in menifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```

Also add playservice in gradle.

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.4.0'
```

You can see my app gradle.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
```

android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.1"

```
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.android.geocoderdemo"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 24
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    multiDexEnabled true
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
```

}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.1.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.4.0'
}

Comment: Thanks, Sachin. Unfortunately, I'm getting a "Error:(5, 0) Could not find method compile() for arguments [com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.4.0] on project ':app' of type org.gradle.api.Project."

Comment: I think there is problem in app gradle.you need to give latest sdk target.i share my gradle .